# Singleton Design Pattern Alternative?

Tags: python, authentication, reporting-services, singleton

I have an portal with the following classes:

- Authorization
- Querying
- Report Generation

For all of these it seems that the singleton design pattern would work best, but I am told that it is highly unadvisable to use it. However, I also see that I only need to authenticate once and query and report multiple times (but the functionality is the same each time). Is there any way to get around this and use a more OOP approach? I am programming in Python by the way. I know there are many posts on this, but **before you yell "duplicate!"** please consider my specific situation. I really just need a yes or no answer as to whether I should use it or not. I've read a ton of documentation and I'm still unsure.

Thank you.

Comment: What is so bad about the singleton pattern?

Comment: When you program in OOP it is generally the inclination that you want to create multiple objects of a class. I've been told it is ill advised due to the fact that it abuses the nature of OOP.

Comment: If you want to instantiate a single instance of your class, then only instantiate one. That being said, if your singleton is just storing data, use a dictionary in a global variable. If it's just for a collection of functions, don't use a class at all, create a module with top level functions.

Comment: More generally, python is not java: http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Comment: @Adam Patterns can be abused. But just because they can be abused, doesn't mean we shouldn't use them. Used properly, the Singleton is a powerful pattern that can solve a number of issues. In fact, in Ruby the Singleton Module is part of std-lib.

Comment: If you need only one of something and that thing is a simple, testable thing then that is a sign of a good design.